# SQL Server replace NULLs with the length of the column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update, window-functions

There is a table

```
foo   bar   id
foo1  bar1  NULL
foo2  bar2  NULL
foo2  bar2  NULL
foo3  bar3  NULL
foo4  bar4  NULL
foo4  bar4  NULL
```

I need to replace the NULL values with the length of the column like, 1,2,3 and so on

```
foo   bar   id
foo1  bar1  1
foo2  bar2  2
foo2  bar2  3
foo3  bar3  4
foo4  bar4  5
foo4  bar4  6
```

I have Googled but did not get how to make it

Comment: What do you call the *length* of the column?

Comment: what do you mean by `lenght of the column` ?

Comment: Do you mean you want some kind of row-number in the id column?

Comment: What do you mean by the "length" of the column? `id` looks like a numerical data type, so it doesn't have a "length" (string types are declared with a length). This looks more like you want to number the **row**, which would be [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: What's expected to happen if somebody later deletes the foo3 row?

Comment: What happens if you have the value `'foo10'`? `'foo10'` has **lower** value than `'foo2'`, so should it have a lower "Length" value too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As commented by jarlh, it looks like you are trying to assign incremental numbers to column `id`, ordered by `foo`, then `bar`:

```
select 
    foo,
    bar,
    case when id is null then row_number() over(order by foo, bar) else id end id
from mytable
```

If you are looking for an update:

```
with cte as (
    select 
        foo,
        bar,
        id,
        row_number() over(order by foo, bar) rn
    from mytable
)
update cte set id = rn
where id is null
```